# Metaprogramming and SFINAE/std::enable_if: infinite template recursion

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, sfinae

Consider the following program:

```
// Include
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

// Base class
template <class Crtp, class... Types>
struct Base
{
    // Constructor calling the transmute function
    template <class... OtherTypes> 
    explicit inline Base(const OtherTypes&... source) 
    : _data(transmute<std::tuple<Types...>>(std::forward_as_tuple(source...))) 
    {;}

    // Transmute: create a new object
    template <class Output> 
    static constexpr Output transmute() 
    {return Output();}

    // Transmute: forward existing object
    template <class Output, 
              class Input, 
              class = typename std::enable_if<
                          std::is_convertible<
                              typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<Input>::type>::type, 
                              typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<Output>::type>::type
                          >::value
                      >::type> 
    static constexpr Input transmute(Input&& input) 
    {return std::forward<Input>(input);} 

    // Transmute: recursive transmutation
    template <class Output, 
              class... Input, 
              class = typename std::enable_if<
                          (sizeof...(Input) <= std::tuple_size<Output>::value) 
                          && (sizeof...(Input) != std::tuple_size<Output>::value)
                      >::type>
    static constexpr Output transmute(const Input&... input) 
    {return transmute<Output>(input..., typename std::tuple_element<sizeof...(Input), Output>::type());}

    // Transmute: final step
    template <class Output, 
              class... Input, 
              class = typename std::enable_if<
                          (sizeof...(Input) == std::tuple_size<Output>::value) 
                          && (sizeof...(Input) != 0)
                      >::type> 
    static constexpr Output transmute(Input&&... input) 
    {return transmute<Output>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Input>(input)...));}

    // Data member
    std::tuple<Types...> _data; 
};

// Derived class
struct Derived
: public Base<Derived, std::string, bool>
{
    // Universal reference constructor
    template <class... Misc> 
    explicit inline Derived(Misc&&... misc) 
    : Base<Derived, std::string, bool>(std::forward<Misc>(misc)...) 
    {;}
};

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Derived a("hello"); // Boom !!!!
    return 0;
}
```

If you try to compile it, the compiler will "explode", throwing a quite impressive error with templates of templates of templates...

My question is quite simple: where is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Thus is akin to posing an entire program and input, and saying it 'crashes when I run it.  What goes wrong?'  Do fewer things.  Test each component.  Find a change that goes from tested and working to tested and failing.  Include copious documentation about what you are trying to do.  Try to simplify and produce the same error with less cruft.

Comment: `(sizeof...(Input) <= std::tuple_size<Output>::value) 
                          && (sizeof...(Input) != std::tuple_size<Output>::value)` This looks suspicious.

Comment: `: _data(transmute<std::tuple<Types...>>(source...))` and it compiles (removed the `std::forward_as_tuple`). Not sure if it's correct, though. But as far as I understood your metaprogramming, the forwarding as tuple isn't correct: The final step expects all arguments *not* to be wrapped in a tuple; in your current code the `std::tuple<const char(&)[6]>` created from `"hello"` is not convertible to a `std::string`, hence forwarding never occurs.

Comment: +1, I've just found this was the origin of the error like 3 minutes ago.

Comment: @DyP: if you copy/paste your answer I will validate it

Comment: Just accept mpark's. There's no benefit in writing a duplicate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your intention correctly, it looks like what you want is to pass `M` arguments to a `std::tuple<>` of size `N`, where `M <= N`. If `M < N`, fill in the arguments that aren't provided with default constructed values of the type.

If that's the case, the constructor for `Base` should be:

```
template <class... OtherTypes>
explicit inline Base(const OtherTypes&... source)
: _data(transmute<std::tuple<Types...>>(source...))
{;}
```

So that it will go through the recursive, final, then `forward_as_tuple`.

**Alternative Solution:**

**NOTE:** Implementation of `std::integer_sequence` and related helpers are omitted. You can refer to the paper [N3658](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3658.html) and an implementation [here](https://gitorious.org/redistd/integer_seq/source/fdce85d18df4ea99240524c626d5452a0f7c3faf%3ainteger_seq.h).

```
template <typename T, typename Seq, T Begin>
struct make_integer_range_impl;

template <typename T, T... Ints, T Begin>
struct make_integer_range_impl<T, std::integer_sequence<T, Ints...>, Begin>
    : public std::common_type<std::integer_sequence<T, Begin + Ints...>> {};

/* Similar to std::make_integer_sequence<>, except it goes from [Begin, End)
   instead of [0, Size). */
template <typename T, T Begin, T End>
using make_integer_range = typename make_integer_range_impl<
    T, std::make_integer_sequence<T, End - Begin>, Begin>::type;

/* Similar to std::make_index_sequence<>, except it goes from [Begin, End)
   instead of [0, Size). */
template <std::size_t Begin, std::size_t End>
using make_index_range = make_integer_range<std::size_t, Begin, End>;

/* Trivial wrapper for std::tuple_element<>. */
template <std::size_t Idx, typename Tuple>
using tuple_element_t = typename std::tuple_element<Idx, Tuple>::type;

template <typename... Args>
class Partial {
  public:

  /* Our tuple type. */
  using Tuple = std::tuple<Args...>;

  /* Create an index_range, [# of arguments, tuple size),
     and forward the arguments to the delegating constructor. */
  template <typename... ForwardArgs>
  Partial(ForwardArgs &&... forward_args)
      : Partial(make_index_range<sizeof...(ForwardArgs),
                                 std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>(),
                std::forward<ForwardArgs>(forward_args)...) {}

  private:

  /* The given indices are for the missing arguments, get the corresponding
     types out of the tuple and default construct them. */
  template <std::size_t... Indices, typename... ForwardArgs>
  Partial(std::index_sequence<Indices...> &&, ForwardArgs &&... forward_args)
      : tuple_{std::forward<ForwardArgs>(forward_args)...,
               tuple_element_t<Indices, Tuple>{}...} {}

  /* Our tuple instance. */
  Tuple tuple_;

};  // Partial<Args...>
```